# Twilio iOS conference call/voip morocco

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip, conference

I'm from Belgium and I did a app which uses VOIP and conference call from twilio.

All work perferctly in my country but when the "test" team in morocco try the application there is several issues with the conference call.
The song starts (so the device is well connected to the conference) but the song stops after 3 -4 sec without any reason.
In Belgium (with the two device used for testing) there's no issue, we can even stay in "waiting" phase during 5min without any lag/cut off

The team in morocco finally gets this error :  [ERROR TCMetricsPublisher] Invalid TCCall object.

Any clue ?

Comment: This sounds like something that's best sent to our support team. Please send details, including call SIDs, for calls that have these issues to help@twilio.com and they can help you with your problems.

Comment: I'll try there Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here. I do hope our support team was able to help with this issue.

`Invalid TCCall object` doesn't appear to be a Twilio error as there is no reference available in the [iOS client SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios).

It would definitely be helpful to see more detail from your iOS logs and the point of failure.